# How to fix my implementation of multiple-vector ZigZag Iterator?

Tags: c++

This is my implementation of multiple-vector ZigZagIterator problem:
(Full task description here:
https://ttzztt.gitbooks.io/lc/content/zigzag-iterator.html)
However, it does not work properly and I clearly try to iterate over non-existing elements.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ZigZagIterator {
    int k;
    deque<pair<vector<int>::iterator, vector<int>::iterator>>
        order;   // it.begin(), it.end()

  public:
    template <typename T, typename... Args> ZigZagIterator(T t, Args... args) {
        init(t, args...);
    }

    template <typename T> void init(T t) {
        if constexpr (is_same_v<T, int>) {
            cout << "solo-init | t is int\n";
            k = t;
        } else {
            cout << "solo-init | t is NOT int\n";
            order.push_back(make_pair(t.begin(), t.end()));
        }
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args> void init(T t, Args... args) {
        if constexpr (is_same_v<T, int>) {
            cout << "multi-init | t is int\n";
            k = t;
        } else {
            cout << "multi-init | t is NOT int\n";
            order.push_back(make_pair(t.begin(), t.end()));
        }
        init(args...);
    }

    int next_elem() {
        cout << "DEBUG | order.size() == " << order.size() << "\n";
        while (!order.empty() && order.front().first == order.front().second) {
            order.pop_front();
            cout << "DEBUG | empty element deleted!\n";
        }
        if (order.empty()) {
            cout << "Queue ended!\n";
            return -1;
        }
        auto current = order.front();
        order.pop_front();
        cout << "TEST  | " << *current.first << "\n";
        /*
        Next or it++ tyrade
            Although the expression ++c.begin() often compiles, it is not
            guaranteed to do so: c.begin() is an rvalue expression, and
            there is no LegacyInputIterator requirement that specifies that
            increment of an rvalue is guaranteed to work. In particular,
            when iterators are implemented as pointers or its operator++ is
            lvalue-ref-qualified,
            ++c.begin() does not compile, while std::next(c.begin()) does.
            TODO: next == advance (?)
        */
        if (next(current.first) != current.second) {
            order.push_back(make_pair(next(current.first), current.second));
        }
        return *current.first;
    }
};
```

However, testing it like this I see that I clearly did something wrong.

```
int
main() {
    vector<int> first = {1, 4, 7};
    vector<int> second = {2, 5, 8};
    vector<int> third = {3, 6, 9};
    ZigZagIterator zigzag(3, first, second, third);
    while (zigzag.next_elem() != -1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Output:

```
multi-init | t is int
multi-init | t is NOT int
multi-init | t is NOT int
solo-init | t is NOT int
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 4
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 0
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 2
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 1073741824
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 1073741824
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 1073741824
DEBUG | order.size() == 3
TEST  | 326502032
DEBUG | order.size() == 2
TEST  | 0
DEBUG | order.size() == 1
TEST  | 0
DEBUG | order.size() == 0
Queue ended!
```

The correct output is expected to be:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: please make the question self contained by including a description of what the code is supposed to do in the quesiton directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> ZigZagIterator(T t, Args... args) {
    init(t, args...);
}
```

And everywhere else you are making copies of the vectors that are passed. Hence the iterators you store in the queue are invalid by the time you dereference them.

Changing the constructor and the other methods to pass the vectors by reference

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> ZigZagIterator(T t, Args&... args) {
    init(t, args...);
}
```

fixes the output: https://godbolt.org/z/z6KMo4EYP.

---

While this fixes the immediate problem with the code, there is more to fix. For example the recursive templates are unnecessary complexity. Your code anyhow only works for `std::vector<int>` (thats the type of iterator you store in the queue). You could use a initializer list constructor to accept arbitrary number of vectors of `int`.